# How to show download manager progress in my listview progress bar

Tags: java, android, android-download-manager

I want to show progress bar for download using download manager in listview. I tried below code it is not working as i want. I have multiple files to download on single click of listview item. I want single progress bar for all the files of that list item click to be shown in that listview item progress dialog.

**FileDownloader.java**

```
public class FileDownloader {
    private DownloadManager downloadManager;
    private long downloadReferenceId;
    ArrayList<Long> ReferenceIdlist = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;
    DBHandler dbHandler;
    OfferingEntries of = new OfferingEntries();

    public FileDownloader(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        dbHandler = new DBHandler(context);       
    }

    public void DownloadData(ArrayList<String> filepaths, final ProgressBar view) {
        for (int i = 0; i < filepaths.size(); i++) {
            downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            String urlString = "http://192.168.1.55/...";
            urlString = urlString.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
            Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse(urlString);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);
            request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI|DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
            request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
            request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false);
            request.setTitle("Data:" + filepaths.get(i));
            request.setDescription("Downloading " + filepaths.get(i));
            request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/" + "myfiles" , filepaths.get(i));
            downloadReferenceId = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
            ReferenceIdlist.add(downloadReferenceId);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    boolean downloading = true;
                    while (downloading) {
                        DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
                        q.setFilterById(downloadReferenceId); //filter by id which you have receieved when reqesting download from download manager

                        Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(q);
                        cursor.moveToFirst();

                        int bytes_downloaded = cursor.getInt(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));

                        int bytes_total = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));                            
                        if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)) == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
                            downloading = false;
                        }

                        final int dl_progress = (int) ((bytes_downloaded * 100l) / bytes_total);                            
                        ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                view.setProgress((int) dl_progress);
                            }
                        });
                        cursor.close();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
}
```

**ListView click code**

```
lesson_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String sel_lesson_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lesson_id)).getText().toString();
        ProgressBar v=(ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.bar);
        of.setLesson_id(sel_lesson_id);
        String course_id=of.getCourse_id();

        ArrayList<String> filepaths=dbHandler.getFiles(course_id,sel_lesson_id);
        ArrayList<String> newfilepaths = (ArrayList<String>)filepaths.clone();
        File extStore = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

        for(int i = 0; i < filepaths.size(); i++) {
            File myFile = new File(extStore.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + of.getOffering_id() + "/" + of.getLesson_id() + "/" + filepaths.get(i));
            if (myFile.exists()) {
                newfilepaths.remove(filepaths.get(i));
            }
        }

        if (newfilepaths.size() == 0) {
            /*Fragment fragment = null;
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragment = new PdfReader();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();*/
            LessonNavigator ln=new LessonNavigator(getActivity());
            ln.navigate();

        } else {
            isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
            if (!isInternetPresent) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No internet connection!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                FileDownloader fd;
                //view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                //view.setClickable(false);
                //view.setFocusable(false);
                fd = new FileDownloader(getActivity());
                fd.DownloadData(filepaths,v);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Files are being downloaded...Please check the progress in notification bar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `I want single progress bar for all the files of that list item click to be shown in that listview item progress dialog.`. You will have only one bar i think. So what is it that does not go as you want?

Comment: i have only one bar....but the files are multiple...i want to show one bar for multple files. The arraylist 'filepaths ' contains the files to be downloaded

Comment: `So what is it that does not go as you want?`. You did not answer my question. You did not tell which problem you have. Or what the difficulty would be doing so.

Comment: I'm getting progress for each file in the arraylist. I want   one progress bar for all the files in arraylist. Hope you understand while checking my code

Comment: Why should i check your code? I first wanna know what you want. After that which problems you have implementing it. I know now what you want. But only half. You did not even tell what you want to display. For instance if you have 8 files with total 135 MB. Then what should we see? 0-8? Or 0-135MB? Or 0-100%?

Comment: if there are 8 files total of 135 mb i want to display a progressbar from 0 to 100%. Not each bar for each file. Instead i want to show one bar for all files.

Comment: You forget to tell if 100% would be equal to 135 MB or equal to 8. That is a big difference. Hope you understand that. Please explain the difference and the difficulties.

Comment: both are equal i hope if 100% is equal to 135mb then all files have been downloaded

Comment: Yes than all is downloaded. But. No. Not both are equal!!! Implementing for 8 is pretty easy. What is the difficulty if 100% would be 135MB?

Comment: I want to know how to implement for 8. In the sense 1 out of 8, 2 out of 8 etc

Comment: i have many list items in listview. user can click as many number of listview. So concurrently i want to show bar for all the listviews. for eg 1st listview when clicked downloads 8 files, so show bar for 8 files in that view and 2nd listview when clicked downloads 5 files so show bar for 5 files in that

Comment: Well that is not to difficult. Please explain the problem you have setting a max of 8 for a progressbar and incrementing position every time you downloaded a file.

Comment: Are you now teling that every item of your listview has its own progressbar?

Comment: yes. Every item has its own progressbar. So user can download files concurrently

Comment: `So concurrently i want to show bar for all the listviews. ` ??? For all items? So confusnig!

Comment: `for eg 1st listview when clicked` ?? You mean first item of your listview? You will have only one listview i think. Confusing!

Comment: when 1st listview item is clicked,show bar for 8 files in that view. after that while downloading in progress. if user clicks on 2nd item of listview download 5 files and show bar in that view. So every listview item has its own progress bar. and when that item is clicked i want to download its own files and show progress in its progress bar

Comment: Ok so when the user quickly clicks three items then for instance 8+5+9 files will get downloaded. Ok. It is a pitty that you did not tell all of this in the first lines of your post.

Comment: yes. and show 8 in first listview item bar, 5 in second and 9 in 3rd

Comment: Well lets first concentrate on only one item clicked. I repeat: `Please explain the problem you have setting a max of 8 for a progressbar and incrementing position every time you downloaded a file.`.

Comment: Also: while during download the use scrolls that specific item out of view and then back again in view you will have additional problems finding out the new progressbar for the new view. Have you thought on that?

Comment: i know that problem as well. thats why i posted the entire thing here. 'Please explain the problem you have setting a max of 8 for a progressbar and incrementing position every time you downloaded a file' i did not understand this

Comment: So before coding for download you should just write a little bit of code that slowly increments a progressbar on a listview item. And that even works when items are scrolled. Use a timer to increment the position of the bar.

Comment: And then again i do not understand that you do not understand that you have to set a maximum of 8 for a progressbar and have to increment its position.

Comment: `i know that problem as well.`. You should have told us all these problems right away. You did not describe any problem. We are here to help you with your problems. Not to write the code for you for features you want.